# How to build CLM in android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am building clm in android, my .mk file look like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

LOCAL_MODULE    := sample_CLM_SO_File

FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)


FILE_LIST1 := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Users/caffe/caffe-android-lib/Boost-for-Android/build/lib/*.a)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST1:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_CPP_INCLUDES := /Users/caffe/caffe-android-lib/Boost-for-Android/build/include/boost-1_55/boost

LOCAL_CPP_INCLUDES := /Users/caffe/caffe-android-lib/opencv2/jni/include

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The .so file is generated but .o file isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer to Build CLM in android using Androidndk. In Application.mk file i did mistake i didnt add CPP_FLAGS -std=c++11.

My Application.mk file look like this

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

Finally i build so generation for CLM